# How can i cross when clicking a button next to it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Hi im a beginner on javascript and I am trying to code a shopping file page for exercising. Below in the code i can add new things on my shopping list but what i want to do is that when i click Done button i want to cross ( using "line-through" ) the item next to the done button and if i press it again i want it to become normal. What can i do ?

Here is my js code :
Here i am creating the element that user writes and adding it to the list, after i am creating a done button next to it.

```
function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);

    var button  = document.createElement("button");
    button.className = "done";
    button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Done"));
    li.appendChild(button); 


    input.value = "";
}
```

Below the code amongst many things that i have tried but evidently none of them worked

```
document.querySelectorAll('.done').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    //handle click
   // alert("asdasd");
    li.style.textDecoration="line-through";
  })
})
```

[Here is the look of my page:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9maj.png)

And the html here :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shopping List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shoppinglist.css">
    
</head>
<body>
<div class="bg">
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>

    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button class="enter" id="enter">Enter</button>


    <ul>
        <li>Lemon  <button>Done</button></li> 
        <li>Orange  <button>Done</button></li>

    </ul>
</div>
    



<script type="text/javascript" src="shoppingscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Let us see what your HTML looks like.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add. You can find it now.

Comment: WOuld make more sense with a checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To toggle the line through effect you can add a class, and use the `classList.toggle` method for the `li`.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', e =>
  {
    const item = document.getElementById('item');
    
    item.classList.toggle('done');
  });
```

```css
.done
{
  text-decoration:line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li id="item">
 hello
 </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="toggle"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use classes for this sort of thing, add a `span` around the text to facilitate the strike through using that class.

Since you are dynamically adding the button by class https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName  I put the click event listener by class.  You could add that listener right when you create the button also, up to you when you add that.

Then just toggle the class https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList when you click the button by finding the `span` with the text using `.previousSibling` of the target of the event (the DONE button) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling

```js
function createListElement(ul, value) {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  // add a span so we can toggle the class on it
  let s = document.createElement("span");
  s.textContent = value;
  li.appendChild(s);
  ul.appendChild(li);

  let button = document.createElement("button");
  button.className = "done";
  button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Done"));
  li.appendChild(button);
}

function doneClicked(event) {
  let classToToggle = "strike";
  console.log(event.target.previousSibling);
  event.target.previousSibling.classList.toggle(classToToggle, !event.target.previousSibling.classList.contains(classToToggle));
}
// create something
var ul = document.getElementById("myul");
let value = "Cheese Biscuts";
createListElement(ul, value);
createListElement(ul, 'Water Buffalos');
let dones = document.getElementsByClassName("done");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dones.length; i++) {
  dones[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    doneClicked(event)
  }, false);
}
```

```css
.strike {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<span class="strike">WANNABE TEST TEXT</span>

<ul id="myul">
</ul>
```

Comment: Your answer was pretty helpful thank you, but the problem was it wasnt working with the items that i added manually, it was working only with water buffolas and chese biscuits, because you only define dones array at the beginning. As a solution i added a List is ready button and when i clicked that button i define dones array . As a result problem resolved. Appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Hence my comment that the event handler is only added to existing items when it runs, understanding how dynamically added element play into this is a great step forward.